# First order logical formula for "one of x"

Tags: logic

Considering the following sentence:

> Almost one of five women earn more money than her partner.

I can partly translate this to the following first order predicate logical formula:
(assuming that a partner ship is 'traditional')

> $\exists x,y~|~Woman(x) \wedge Man(y) \wedge PartnerOf(x,y) \wedge MakesMore(x,y)$

But how can I introduce the "one of x" into this formula?

Comment: I think that "almost" is not easy to handle ... With "one of ..." are you meaning : "at least one of ..." (i.e.$\exists$) or "exactly one of ..." (i.e.$\exists !$) ?

Comment: I believe we can drop the "almost" part (although the assignment is very unclear). How could I formulate "exactly one in 5" ?

Comment: given that a probabilistic statement is difficult to transate in a first-predicate formula, actually I would use two statements: exists a set of six couples where exists a woman who earns more than her husband, and exists a set of five couples where no woman earns more than her husband.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the meaning to of "one in $n$ satisfies $\varphi$" to be (among finite models) "the set of individuals satisfying $\phi$ is at least $\frac{1}{n}$ the size of the set of all individuals", there is no way to state this in first-order logic.

To simplify matters, assume we have a first-order language with only the unary predicate symbol $P$ as a nonlogical symbol, and suppose that $\psi$ is a sentence in this language meaning "one in $n$ satisfies $P$."

For each natural number $k$ we can construct sentences $\theta_k$ and $\sigma_k$ with the following meanings:

- $\theta_k$: at least $k$ distinct individuals satisfy $P$;
- $\sigma_k$: at least $k$ distinct individuals do not satisfy $P$.

A relatively easy [compactness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) argument shows that both $$\Sigma_+ = \{ \psi , \theta_1 , \sigma_1 , \theta_2 , \sigma_2 , \ldots \}; \qquad
\Sigma_- = \{ \neg \psi , \theta_1 , \sigma_1 , \theta_2 , \sigma_2 , \ldots \}$$ are consistent.  Furthermore, by the [Löwenheim–Skolem Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), both $\Sigma_+$ and $\Sigma_-$ have countably infinite models.  But it is easy to show that any two countable models of $\{ \theta_1 , \sigma_1 , \theta_2 , \sigma_2 , \ldots \}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Very nice. (I'm not sure if I should leave my attempt as "something not to try" or delete it entirely.)

Comment: As an additonal reference, see: D.Gabbay (editor),*Handbook of Philosophical Logic. Vol 1: Predicate Logic*, page 76 [Wilfrid Hodges's essay on Elem.Predicate Logic]: "Peirce invented the two-thirds quantier which enables us to say 'At least 2/3 of the company have white neckties'. (His
example.) Peirce's quantier was unrestricted. It seems more natural, and changes nothing in principle, if we allow a relativisation predicate and write $2/3x(\psi,\phi)$ to mean 'At least 2/3 of the things $x$ which satisfy $\psi$ satisfy $\phi$'. Can this quantier be defined away? Unfortunately not."

Comment: See also Jouko Vaananen, *Models and Games* (2011), Ch.10 : **Generalized Quantifiers**, for a detailde treatment of the topic, including the *at-least-one-half* quantifier (page 286).

Answer (score 1):

See [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arthur-fischer)'s [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775493/89895) for the answer to the problem. Take the following as a couple of failed attempts.

---

$\fbox{1}$ A natural way of doing it would be to quantify over subsets of the domain:

> $\forall_{\langle 5, W, S\rangle}\phi(S)$ is true iff every set S of size 5 consisting of women (W) satisfies formula $\phi.$

The way this works is simple. Given a structure with domain $D$, predicate letter '$W$' has as its extension some subset of $D$, namely, the subset consisting of all women. The special quantifier selects every subset S of size 5 among that extension of $W$ and passes it to the second-order predicate $\phi$. All that is left is to define $\phi(X)$ s.t. it is true just in case there exists (at least, at most, a unique: all easily definable in terms of the standard quantifiers) someone in $X$ who earns more money than her husband (you already know how to approach this).

---

$\fbox{2}$ Since the language must be first-order, we can't quantify over subsets of the domain, so we can use iterations of standard quantifiers to do the job of the quantifier above, e.g. in the following way:

> $\forall_{\langle 5, W, S\rangle}\phi(S) ~=_{df}~ \forall x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 ((Wx_1 \land \ldots \land Wx_5) \rightarrow (\phi(x_1) \lor \ldots \lor \phi(x_5)))$

There's a natural way of generalizing this to any size and predicate. If you want "exactly" 5 or "at most" 5, you have to add more stuff to the consequent; this one only covers the "at least" 5 case.

Comment: The only problem is : have we to stay with the requirement in the OP's answer regarding a "first order predicate logical formula" ?

Comment: Ah, of course. I completely ignored the restriction. Let's define the beastly quantifier above in terms of the usual ones. I'll update it in a minute.

Comment: Except I don't think that your interpretation of the statement is the usual interpretation: 20% of the individuals of satisfy $\phi$.  You're interpretation seems to reduce to simply "at most $4$ individuals do not satisfy $\phi$."

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes!, I see how it doesn't quite do the job. We need an actually probabilistic treatment of the sentence. I'll leave it as it is and see if other answers will suggest an improvement or will convince me that this is entirely hopeless. Thank you very much for the comment.